# Set bean's property from dynamically generated HTML list

Tags: jquery, html, jsp, jquery-mobile, html-lists

I have a `<ul>` element which I dynamically fill with `<li>` elements. I desire to get control of these `<li>` element, by that I mean to have them able to set a property of my bean with there content. Just to be more explicit : once I click on a `<li>`, I want the text in it to be the value of a property.

Here's the code of the unordered list generation:

```
<div data-role="content">   

<ul data-role="listview" data-inset="true" data-filter="true" data-filter-reveal="true" data-filter-placeholder="Région...">
  <%
     for (int i = 0; i < mdjsBean.getRegionList().size(); i++) {
        String region_ = (String) mdjsBean.getRegionList().get(i) ;
  %>
    <li><a><%= region_ %></a></li>
   <%}%>
</ul>
```

What I hope for is something similar to JSF's `selectOneMenu` tag, it gives you choices and you select one (of which the value will be stored in your bean property).

Any idea about how we might do that in JSP and `<ul>` and `<li>` tags ?

**My requirements** :

[image]

As the picture shows, it's a an [autocomplete widget](http://view.jquerymobile.com/1.3.1/dist/demos/widgets/autocomplete/) of jQuery(mobile), in my case, I so far succeded to retrieve values of "regions" for DB and arrange them in a listview. Type anyting in the textarea and the listview start filtering regions. 
What I hope for is now to click on an element of that listview and have it fill the `mdjsBean.region` property with the choosen region (btw regionList is a list of all regions, this list is filled from DB, with the help of a java function).

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Scriptlets?! It's not entirely clear what you're asking. You can't set a bean property on the client side w/o a request: JS executes on the client, long after the server has run its scriptlets, and after you can do anything with the server side with a form submit or Ajax.

Comment: I know scriptlets are not best practice, but let's not focus on these now. Actually, I somewhat need to reproduce selectOneMenu in JSP, that's the core of my question.

Comment: Except I need the bean for other purposes... Ajax isn't enough.

Comment: Then describe the rest of your requirements. If you want the change reflected on the server, you need Ajax. If you need it on the page, then JS. I'm not sure what you believe the options are here.

Comment: So should I totally abandon the bean usage in my case ? As for the requirement, I'll edit my post to better explain them.

Comment: You still have to put the list on your page on initial render, unless you want to do that with Ajax as well.

Comment: Edited the post, as you can see it's working in a way, it renders, now I'll I want is (if possible) send a choosing value from client to server with the help of a bean's property (much like in JSF).

Comment: also edited the code and the tagging.

Comment: I don't see anything here that isn't simple JS and Ajax, but there's no "beans" on the client side. You can fake it with DWR, which is JS and Ajax. Maybe if you explain why you can't send the selected value to the server and get back either JSON or HTML for your list we'll understand better.

Comment: Ok, the bean-way is just too twisted it apprears, you must be right, I'll shift to Ajax, that's easier. If you wish to post your last answer so I can accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't see anything here that isn't simple JS and Ajax, but there are no "beans" on the client side. You can fake it with DWR, which is JS and Ajax.

Without DWR it's a matter of sending the selected value to the server, getting back either JSON to build the new options with, or HTML and injecting it directly into the DOM. (It's actually the same with DWR, but it's wrapped up in Java-looking JS.)

Depending in your needs it might be a good idea to investigate frameworks that wrap up this process for you, although IMO is important to understand what's going on underneath.

It's not twisted, it's simply not possible: JS=client, bean=server. If you want to update the client with server-side data without a page refresh, Ajax is *the* option (ignoring long connections etc).

Comment: "It's not twisted, it's simply not possible: JS=client, bean=server. If you want to update the client with server-side data without a page refresh, Ajax is the option (ignoring long connections etc).". That's clear, thanks !